# Google Webmaster Tools API crawl issues feed data counts appears wrong

Tags: xml, api, google-api, google-search-console, google-crawlers

I'm using the Webmaster Tools API to get crawl issues, but I'm not sure how the data in the XML feed exactly relates to the data in webmaster tools admin.

E.g.
In `Webmaster Tools > Crawl > Crawl Errors`, it splits URL errors into 3 sections, desktop, smartphone, feature phone, and then further sections inside each of these.
For the account I'm testing on it shows the following:

```
Desktop: server error = 24, soft 404 = 71, not found = 66
Smartphone: server error = 7, blocked = 2
Feature Phone: server error = not found = 1
```

But in the `crawlissues` API feed I get only 93 entry results in total, all marked as `web-crawl` (so I guess that's just desktop only)

```
server error = 19, soft 404 = 22, not found = 52
```

As you can see, the totals don't seem to match up.

Please could someone explain these to me, I also checked yesterdays and the day before's values and they are around the same values in Webmaster Tools but still don't total the same as the values from this feed.

I tried posting this in the google group for it, but haven't had any responses so far and after searching around on google and inside the group I can't find anything helpful.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any updates on this would be great.

Comment: Hi, sorry to say this issue still exists: 
There's a little more detail in these other posts i asked about it btw: 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/gOpqYdrPfII
https://github.com/eyecatchup/GWT_CrawlErrors-php/issues/4